# sailsjs: Avoid saving some form inputs in database

Tags: node.js, forms, model, sails.js

I am trying to make a signup page, following [irl nathans guide](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLf8i4fc0zJBzLhOe6FwHpGhBDgqwInJWZ). Now everything works, however sail.js seems to save everything from the form in the database. For an example, I have this form:

```
<form class="form-signup" name="signup-form" action="/user/create" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="<%= __('username') %>"> %>">
    <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="<%= __('email') %>">
    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="<%= __('password') %>">
    <input type="password" name="confirmation" placeholder="<%= __('confirm-password') %>">
    <input class="button" type="submit" value="<%= __('signup') %>"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="<%= _csrf %>"/>
  </form>
```

In this example it saves both the password and the password-confirmation in the database, which it shouldn't.

In my User.js model I have the following attributes, but these are just saved alongside the two passwords. I also have an encryptedPassword, that encrypts the password if they match.

```
module.exports = {
  attributes: {
username: {
  type: 'string',
  required: true,
  unique: true
},
email: {
  type: 'string',
  required: true,
  isEmail: true,
  unique: true
},
encryptedPassword: {
  type: 'string'
},
// more unimportant code here.
}
```

I would like to know whether and it is possible to prevent sails.js from saving the two unencrypted passwords in the database whenever the form is submitted. I know I can just remove it afterwards from the database, however, that seems kind of stupid.

The saved record in the database, when submitted:

```
 {
    "username": "testuser",
    "password": "2",
    "confirmation": "2",
    "email": "myemail@email.com",
    "createdAt": 1496268539155,
    "updatedAt": 1496268539155,
    "encryptedPassword": "$2a$10$BkwvQnu3TA4DQ1kDMZmi6O7Z/K5uX90fHi/6zkZF.nkKi8MU.zWTS",
    "id": "592f3efbaa4d2563e159dc20"
  }
```

Since I am encrypting the password, it shouldn't also save the unencrypted passwords, just because they were part of the submit form. How do I prevent it from doing so?

Comment: chance that you are saving all incoming req.param to your database in your controller.

Comment: You can use `beforeCreate` callback to delete password from the `values` object.
Refer: http://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/lifecycle-callbacks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for the answers, however, I managed to solve the problem by passing an object to the .create() function. This object contains all the parameters I want to save, instead of using req.params.all().

```
var userObj = {
  username          : req.param('username'),
  firstname         : req.param('firstname'),
  encryptedPassword : password,
  surname           : req.param('surname'),
  email             : req.param('email')
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Where you setup your db connection (connections.js or in your /env/development.js) specify **schema: true**

For example:

```
someDbServer: {
  adapter: 'sails-mongo',
  host: 'localhost',
  port: 27017,
  user: 'username',
  password: 'pwd',
  database: 'db_name',
  schema: true
}
```

Setting schema to true means only attributes in the model js file can be inserted.

For encrypting your password you want to do that in beforeCreate and beforeUpdate. Take a look at lifecycle callbacks -[sailsjs lifecycle callbacks](http://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/lifecycle-callbacks)